# POST call retrofit is not completing itself

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to make a post call using retrofit. But the call is not completed and returns back without response on success side.

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @POST("newUserInitialDetail")
    Call<Response> setBankerInitialDetail(@Body EFueBanker eFueBanker);

}
```

I have its implementation as

```
EFueBanker eFueBanker= SingletonStorage.geteFueBanker();
eFueBanker.setGstno(gstno.getText().toString());
eFueBanker.setNoc(Integer.parseInt(noc.getText().toString()));
mApiInterface= ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<com.shaby.efueprovider.dao.Response> call= mApiInterface.setBankerInitialDetail(eFueBanker);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<com.shaby.efueprovider.dao.Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<com.shaby.efueprovider.dao.Response> call, Response<com.shaby.efueprovider.dao.Response> response) {
                        try {
                            com.shaby.efueprovider.dao.Response response1 = response.body();
                            if (response1.getStatus() == 200) {
                                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(mainIntent);
                                getActivity().finish();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<com.shaby.efueprovider.dao.Response> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I am always getting a toast response from the following call that

> I cannot access `getStatus()` of null

But the interesting thing is that I have another post call where I am sending another object of different class and that is working fine. And another thing that when I don't pass eFueBanker as parameter the call goes successfully.

Comment: `com.shaby.efueprovider.dao.Response` is same in both ? in interface and where you're fetching response ?

Comment: Yes that is same I have checked

Comment: have you tested your URL on `POSTMAN` maybe `getStatus()` is `null`

Comment: it is not even calling the api with the parameter but without parameter it is successfully called

Comment: BTW you can change `response1.getStatus() == 200` with `response.isSuccessful()`

Comment: I am trying that but this is an issue, I will be calling like this several time and not everytime it is same check. I will return value later too

Comment: it has shown false in log

Comment: Did you add any converter for the client like gson? it may be a problem of serialization. In addition, add here the EFueBanker class

Comment: In the similar call other than this I didnot use any of serialization and that is working fine. in this I am getting in response "BAD REQUEST". Is there any issue with static variables?

Comment: @AliAhmed no you can not. isSuccessful checks for more than 200

Answer (score 0):

You can check response code without this assignment

```
com.shaby.efueprovider.dao.Response response1 = response.body();
```

You can check like

```
if (response.code() == 200) {
   Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
   startActivity(mainIntent);
   getActivity().finish();
}
```

Comment: the call itself is not completing so your code works well if it works only in the case when my api call hits the api